# How to determine the number of memory loads generated by write allocate of cacheline?

Tags: caching, intel, profile, perf

According to [this page](https://sites.utexas.edu/jdm4372/2018/01/01/notes-on-non-temporal-aka-streaming-stores/) and [this pag](https://www.stonybrook.edu/commcms/ookami/_pdf/Gosh_UGM2023.pdf)e, a store miss to the L3 cache will occur first with a read operation, and in some cases can be avoided by non-temporal stores.

Is there a way (like some perf events) for me to estimate the number of memory loads caused by such write-allocation in a workload?

Answer (score 1):

The technical term for such reads is *Read For Ownership*, getting the cache line into MESI Exclusive state.  There are perf events specific to `rfo` hits or misses in L2, and for what happens off-core after an L2 miss.  Unlike loads, there aren't per-instruction counters, since stores don't even leave the store buffer until after they're retired.

I had a look at the events `perf list` shows on my Skylake i7 desktop.

`offcore_requests.demand_rfo` might be what you're looking for (and probably is similar to `l2_rqsts.rfo_miss`), but that would count RFOs that hit in L3.

Or perhaps `offcore_response.demand_rfo.l3_miss_local_dram.any_snoop` for a single-socket system, if that does what I think, of counting RFOs that have to access DRAM?  I haven't tried it, but the name looks promising.

**Or `offcore_response.demand_rfo.l3_miss.any_snoop` since the key point is missing in L3.**

In a multi-socket system, I don't know which combinations of events could count local DRAM (this socket) vs. DRAM on other sockets, but not L3 hit on another socket if that's possible.  Apparently `snoop_non_dram` is also possible, perhaps for cacheable device memory that has to go through the system agent instead of the memory controllers?  Or maybe that's covering the possibility of L4 hit in the optional eDRAM cache that some laptop SKL have.

If I recall correctly, `offcore_response` events are probably sensitive to activity on the other logical core, so keep that idle.

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like you are interested in the number of (potentially unnecessary) **DRAM** reads that were caused by store instructions that missed in the caches?

The basic idea of "Read-For-Ownership" is common across a great many processor architectures, but the details vary, and the details are often critical in understanding what the performance counters are actually counting.  Every combination of processor core and uncore has a different set of microarchitectural implementation choices and a different set of hardware performance counter bugs, so it is very hard to generalize.

For a system with Intel Xeon Platinum 8280 processors (Cascade Lake), I tested all 276 of the "interesting" offcore_response events that include "RFO" in the name using the STREAM benchmark (compiled without streaming stores) as the workload.  To avoid thinking about the overhead involved in the initial instantiation of the arrays, I ran each case twice -- once for 10 iterations and once for 20 iterations, then took the difference of the counts as the amount corresponding to 10 iterations of the kernels.  For the problem size I used, I expect to see 500M stores, each of which misses in the caches and causes a Read-For-Ownership from memory.

Results fell into four very distinct categories:

1. 100% of expected value -- all RFOs missing in the L3
2. 62% of expected value -- Demand RFOs missing in the L3
3. 38% of expected value -- L2 HW PF RFOs missing in the L3
4. <1% of expected value -- everything else

In category 1, the events returning 100% of the expected value were:
OCR.ALL_RFO.ANY_RESPONSE
OCR.ALL_RFO.L3_MISS.ANY_SNOOP
OCR.ALL_RFO.L3_MISS_LOCAL_DRAM.ANY_SNOOP
OCR.ALL_RFO.L3_MISS_LOCAL_DRAM.SNOOP_NONE
OCR.ALL_RFO.L3_MISS.SNOOP_NONE

In category 2, the events returning 62% of the expected value were:
OCR.DEMAND_RFO.ANY_RESPONSE
OCR.DEMAND_RFO.L3_MISS.ANY_SNOOP
OCR.DEMAND_RFO.L3_MISS_LOCAL_DRAM.ANY_SNOOP
OCR.DEMAND_RFO.L3_MISS_LOCAL_DRAM.SNOOP_NONE
OCR.DEMAND_RFO.L3_MISS.SNOOP_NONE

In category 3, the events returning 38% of the expected value were:
OCR.ALL_PF_RFO.ANY_RESPONSE
OCR.ALL_PF_RFO.L3_MISS.ANY_SNOOP
OCR.ALL_PF_RFO.L3_MISS_LOCAL_DRAM.ANY_SNOOP
OCR.ALL_PF_RFO.L3_MISS_LOCAL_DRAM.SNOOP_NONE
OCR.ALL_PF_RFO.L3_MISS.SNOOP_NONE
OCR.PF_L2_RFO.ANY_RESPONSE
OCR.PF_L2_RFO.L3_MISS.ANY_SNOOP
OCR.PF_L2_RFO.L3_MISS_LOCAL_DRAM.ANY_SNOOP
OCR.PF_L2_RFO.L3_MISS_LOCAL_DRAM.SNOOP_NONE
OCR.PF_L2_RFO.L3_MISS.SNOOP_NONE

So these events allow us to measure all of the expected RFOs and we see that about 62% are "Demand RFOs" while 38% are "L2 HW PF RFOs".
Re-tested these events using 8,12,16,20,24,28 cores (all in 1 socket) and found that the fraction of Demand RFOs varies slightly, from a low of 54% (low core counts) to a high of 65% (high core counts).

Another big complication arises in Ice Lake Xeon --- the hardware will bypass Read-For-Ownership transactions and convert to a streaming store if the core has overwritten the entire line and the system is sufficiently "busy".  It is not clear what metrics the HW uses to determine "busy", so it is very difficult to control.  For the STREAM benchmark, at high core counts (>1/2 of the cores in use), the HW eliminates enough of the RFO transactions that the code with allocating stores gets within 2%-3% of the performance of the code with streaming stores.

Comment: Thank you so much for such detailed explanation and test. But may I ask what tools and instructions you used to calculate these events? I tried using perf, but it couldn't recognize these event names. I'm working with Intel(R) Xeon(R) Gold 6230R and kernel version 5.14. Thank you again.

Comment: @Frontier_Setter I used perf stat with these event names, but looking at the output of "perf list" it shows many uncore event names as "deprecated" -- your kernel may use the older names or may use yet a different set of names for these events.